# With PostgreSQL foreign data wrappers when inserting, is it more efficient to insert rows in bulk?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bulkinsert, postgresql-9.3, foreign-data-wrapper

So, if I have a number of records I want to insert into a foreign table, I could do this (pseudocode):

```
DO
    INSERT INTO my_fdw_table VALUES next_row;
LOOP
```

or this:

```
INSERT INTO my_fdw_table SELECT all_the_rows;
```

To my intuitions, the second seems more efficient, because all the data is sent in one go, with less repeated SQL keywords.

However, I don't know whether the second would really result in just as many round trips. I also don't know or whether or the second would risk hitting some kind of statement length limit if there were a lot of rows?

I'm using postgres 9.3

Comment: Bulk insert is almost *always* substantially faster than single-row inserts. but that's not answering the more interesting question how exactly foreign tables handle bulk-insert internally ...

Comment: You are probably correct, but you won't know until you measure the performance.

Answer (score 1):

The difference will not be enormous, because even a bulk `INSERT` will result in many single `INSERT`s on the foreign server, so there will be the same number of round trips in both cases.

If there is a measurable difference at all, I'd suspect that it is because the client or PL/pgSQL code handling the `INSERT` loop takes some time. Of course, if you do something like running each `INSERT` in its own transaction or using dynamic SQL for the `INSERT` statement, you'll be slower because of that.

Comment: Wouldn't a lot of inserts run locally (local within the foreign server - basically round trips to the disk) be a lot faster than a lot of network round-trips?

Comment: Yes, they would be, but that's not the way it works. Each inserted row requires a round trip between the local and the remote server. The only saving grace is that prepared statements can be used.